# Welcome 'username' in a session

Tags: php, session, admin

I want to display Welcome Admin once the user logs in. I have the current code. What should I write to complete it? I have a mysql database with 'username' I need to replace the username variable.

```
<?php

if((isset($_SESSION['admin']))){
echo "Welcome ......
}
else
{
?>
    <p>Welcome Guest</p>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: You do have `session_start();` loaded, *right*?

Comment: Yes. I only put that fraction of code

Comment: your missing a quote on your echo. What have you tried to access your database?

Comment: Save the name of the user in session, then you can use "Welcome   {$_SESSION['username']}". If the "admin" key has the username, you can use it.

Comment: @Joe Because if he already has the name, don't need to assign it to an other key in SESSION.

Comment: because I want to include other usernames in my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's assume user logs in, and correct credentials are set.

So we set a session with the username (in this case Script47). So something like this.

```
// Blah blah above user logs in...
// $username is the value of the login form. You have now set SESSION "username" to that value
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

There after, when on a "main" page (the page after login) have this.

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
    echo 'Welcome Guest.';
} else {
    echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['username'];
}
```

***Don't forget to start session when setting session.***